# PostSharp attribute not inherited

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

I've created a type-level aspect in PostSharp, it adds some method preprocessing. I've applied it to the class, it works as advertised. However, in the classes derived from that one, it does not - method entry code is not hit.

How do I make my aspect inheritable, please?

I've tried adding `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=true)]` to the aspect class - no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set AttributeInheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast

Read more about it in the documentation

[Mulicast Attribute (Aspect) inheritance](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/deeper-into-aspect-inheritance.aspx)